# ¿Como puedo solucionar el Posicionamiento del Footer?

Tags: javascript, html, css, error404

Les comento, normalmente utilizo bordes para poder guiarme con lad distintas etiquetas que me otorga HTML, pero en el momento de posicionar el FOOTER, me acarca todo lo que vendria siendo el contenido. Mi pregunta es: ¿Hay algo malo con mi codigo? Espero con ansias sus respuestas.

Esta Zona es del HTML
.[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Esta Es del CSS "cuerpo"
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Esta es del CSS "Encabezado"
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Tu código como texto por favor

Comment: Por favor, pon el código como texto. Nadie va a transcribir tu código desde una imagen, por lo que haces más difícil que te ayuden de forma precisa y oportuna. Nadie te va a responder con una imagen por la misma razón.

Answer (score 0):

En lo que a mi concierne esta bien tu código, ahora yo cuando deseo posicionar el footer y que se mantenga abajo lo que hago es:

```
/*1 Primero colocar un alto minimo a body*/
body{
  min-height: 100vh;
}
/*2 Le digo al footer que debe estar abajo puedo hacerlo de 3 maneras */
/*Modo 1*/
body{
  position: relative;
}
footer{
  position: absolute; /* puede ser fixed según se desee*/
  bottom: 0px;
  left: 0px;
}
/*Modo 2*/
body{
  display: flex; /* No es obligatorio*/
}
header{
  order: 1;
}
div#content{
order: 2;
}
footer{
  order: 3;
position: relative;
bottom: 0;
  left: 0px;
}
/*Modo 4*/
/*
Aveces con solo colocar min-height basta
*/
```

Espero te pueda ayudar.

Answer (score 0):

Podrias darle un height predeterminado. De todas formas, utilizaria flexbox para posicionar todos los elementos y luego ya iria ajustando con margin o padding en caso de ser necesario.
De esta manera, te ahorraras muchos (por no decir todos) br y podras realizar un html mas limpio.

Te pongo un recurso bastante bueno para flex.
https://flexboxfroggy.com/